# NetSuite: How can I get a list of custom fields using suitesql or REST?

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

Using the REST suiteql query endpoint or the records endpoints, is there a way to query NetSuite to get a list of custom fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SuiteQL to list customfields.

For example to list entity custom fields:

```
{
"q": "SELECT * FROM CustomField where fieldtype = 'ENTITY'"
}
```

Use **Setup** -> **Records Catalog** to see the records you can query. It includes custom records and custom lists. ex. If you have a custom list called customlist_year then the records browser will include it and you can do a query like: `SELECT * FROM customlist_year` with SuiteQL.

One caveat: SuiteQL is still in development so the fieldnames and results might change with a NetSuite release. Make sure things get tested with a Release Preview account so you are ready for any changes when they hit your production account.

Answer (score 1):

Using RESTWEB Services you can fetch the schemas of the objects. Below is the screen shot which gives the sample rest web service request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX62R.png)

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason to use suiteqql? With a normal RESTlet you can load a dummy record and read all field names starting with "cust".

Comment: I need to use web services